# Why does except not allow me to enter correct value after catching error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, try-except

I have a variable 'action' which I want to input from the user and validate, I have a while loop and a try-except block to catch the values which raise an error or are invalid according to the functionality of the rest of the code

```
while True: # Input and validation of 'action'
        try:
            action = int(input('Please enter what you would like to do: '))
            if action < 0:
                negativeError = ValueError('This value is negative')
                raise negativeError
            if action != 1 or action != 6:
                invalidValueError = ValueError('Not a valid option')
                raise invalidValueError
            break
        except:
            ValueError or TypeError
            print('That is invalid, please enter a valid number corresponding to one of the actions above')
            continue
```

If I input for example 1 on the first iteration, it breaks out of the loop as expected, but if I input -5 (which except catches) on the first iteration THEN input 1 in the second iteration it catches it as if 1 is an invalid value and does not break out of the loop and keeps iterating. I am new to error handling so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. Use `except ValueError` and `continue` instead of `continues`.

Comment: @JanWilamowski Thank you, I changed the syntax to the appropriate one but the same problem occurs, except now entering 1 does not break out of the loop

Comment: @LancelotduLac I raise them in the case of action being less than 0 or being not equal to 1 or 6, currently 1 and 6 are the only valid inputs but later I'll add more and adjust it accordingly

Comment: Isn't action != 1 or action != 6 always true because it cannot be both?

Comment: @LancelotduLac - They're both defined on the respective lines above, not sure why they're needed though

Comment: "If I input for example 1 on the first iteration, it breaks out of the loop as expected" It doesn't. No value can satisfy the `action != 1 or action != 6` check. You need an `and` instead of an `or`.

Comment: @Olli Yeah that was my mistake thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your if statement is not correct.
- Print the message generated during the except raising instead of creating a new message.

```py
while True: # Input and validation of 'action'
    try:
        action = int(input('Please enter what you would like to do: '))
        if action < 0:
            negativeError = ValueError('This value is negative')
            raise negativeError
        if not (action == 1 or action == 6):
            invalidValueError = ValueError('Not a valid option')
            raise invalidValueError
        break
    except (ValueError,TypeError ) as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should look like this:

```
while True: # Input and validation of 'action'
        try:
            action = int(input('Please enter what you would like to do: '))
            if action < 0:
                negativeError = ValueError('This value is negative')
                raise negativeError
            if action not in [1, 6]:
                invalidValueError = ValueError('Not a valid option')
                raise invalidValueError
            break
        except ValueError or TypeError:
            print('That is invalid, please enter a valid number corresponding to one of the actions above')
            continue
```

action != 1 or action != 6 is always true.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this. We'll use a default parameter value for now. This can be modified later (i.e., passed by the caller) thus obviating the need to modify this code:

```
def get_action(valid_actions=[1,6]):
    action_list = ','.join(map(str, valid_actions))
    while True:
        try:
            input_ = input(f'Please select an action from this list {action_list}: ')
            response = int(input_)
            if response in valid_actions:
                return response
            raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid response. Try again')

get_action()
```

Subsequently you might want to add another action - say 3. In which case:

```
get_action([1,3,6])
```

...is all that you'd need